# USB3.0 connection problem with NanoPi M4

Tags: usb, armbian

I have a single board computer NanoPi-M4 which has 4 USB3.0 ports and use Armbian OS which is "a Debian and Ubuntu based computer operating system for ARM development boards.".

The problem is, when I use a USB3.0 device (especially camera, called ZWO asi178), after I boot my pc with the usb cabled connected, my device is always recognized as USB2 device (I can check this with `lsusb -t` and its data transfer speed is "480M").

Then I unplug the cable and replug it to the PC, the device is recognized as USB3.0 device (i.e. the data transfer speed becomes "5000M"). Actually the operation of this camera should be done automatically so the camera has to be recognized as USB3.0 automatically as well.

I have tried something like below to do plug/unplug with commands but this doesn't change anything

```
> sudo sh -c 'echo 6-1 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind'

> sudo sh -c 'echo 6-1 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind'
```

The environment of my pc is

> Linux nanopim4 4.4.179-rk3399 #1 SMP Thu Jun 27 23:31:19 CEST 2019 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Hope anyone has some ideas to fix this problem.
Thank you

Edit:
Once my device is recognized as USB3.0, even after rebooting my pc, the device is seen as USB3.0 but if I do shutdown and boot operation, the device appears as USB2.0 device.

Comment: It could be a power adapter issue: not enought power is provided, so the device fallback to lower-speed, energy saving mode.

Comment: Even if so, I think that doesn't explain why the device can be recognized as USB3.0 after unplug/replug operation.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue now?